# Execute Grunt task using NodeJS cluster

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have a Grunt task and currently I am utilising AsyncJS to run it. AsyncJS worked well but still I feel like it can be more powerful if I can utilise NodeJS cluster to run it. I have checked out Grunt Parallel and Grunt Concurrent and it is not much different to what I doing in my Grunt task. Any suggestions on utilising NodeJS cluster module to speed up Task execution.

Currently I am doing like this

```
 var queue = async.queue(task, function(task, cb){ 
     // Process task with PhantomJS and then
     cb(); 
 }, require('os').cpus().length);

 async.each(htmlPages, function(val, cb) { 
     queue.push(val, function() {
         cb();
     }); 
 }, function() {
     console.log('Completed');
     done();
 });
```

How can I make this work with NodeJS cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to spawn the number of workers that you want using the `cluster` module. Then send messages to them when you want to start them working on something.

Below is code that initialises `os.cpus().length` workers and a `queue` that sends the work to them. It then pushes everything in `htmlPages` to that queue, waits for it to finish and then finally kills all the workers.

```
var os = require('os');
var async = require('async');
var cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isWorker) {

  process.on('message', function(msg) {

    // Do the Phantom JS stuff

    process.send(theResult);
  });

}

if (cluster.isMaster) {

  var workers = os.cpus().map(function () {
    return cluster.fork();
  });

  var queue = async.queue(function (msg, cb) {
    var worker = workers.pop();

    worker.once('message', function (msg) {
      workers.push(worker);
      cb(null, msg);
    });

    worker.send(msg);
  }, workers.length);

  async.each(htmlPages, queue.push.bind(queue), function (err) {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    workers.forEach(function (worker) {
      worker.kill();
    });

    console.log('Completed');
  });

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had almost lost hope :) Will try this and let you know.

Comment: I tried to execute your code as Grunt task and here is the code and it's output http://pastie.org/9900139#. But it seems that same task is being run multiple times? Is my observation correct?

Comment: That is because when running `cluster.fork()` the new fork will enter at the top of the file, and thus run everything again. You must make sure to put the `isWorker` and/or `isMaster` at the top of the file. I fixed your file for you, have a look at the version history here: https://gist.github.com/LinusU/7eebf8fbf845d3512628/revisions.

Comment: The diff is a bit weird since I changed the indentation but what I did was: 1) move the `if (cluster.isWorker)` block to the top of the file, 2) added a `return` statement to the end of that block and 3) removed the `if (cluster.isMaster)` check since that is now redundant. When entering as a worker, the file will be stopped at line 14.

Comment: If I send options to task it is failed. Could you please help  on this. I am running like `grunt jasmine:specConfig`

Comment: Actually, it just occurred to me that PhantomJS is a standalone environment. How are you executing it? It will probably spawn a child anyways so doing the cluster solution is just wasted overhead. Just use [async.eachLimit(arr, limit, iterator, callback)](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachLimit) and you'll be good.

Comment: I think you are correct. But any other way I can use cluster properly with PhantomJS. And I am using async parallel function. As of now it works fine for me.

Comment: Running a cluster with PhantomJS would involve writing something that accepts messages, runs the work and message back within PhantomJS itself. Not in Node.js. Both is javascript thought. This documentation page at PhantomJS should get you started: http://phantomjs.org/inter-process-communication.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70560/discussion-between-redv-and-linus-unneback).

Comment: Currently I am doing the same. Thanks.